# ORDER BY doesn't sort alphabetically

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, sql-order-by

I use the following MySQL query to get results, sorted alphabetically by name:

```
SELECT * FROM `client` WHERE CONCAT(name, ', ', firstname) LIKE "%ti%" ORDER BY name
```

In some way the results get sorted, so the ORDER BY works. Unfortunately it works not as expected. The above query gives the following order for example:

```
Kostic (31)
Hatscher (30)
```

Why is Kostic listed first? Prove me wrong, but K comes after H in the alphabet... (If it helps - the name field is type of varchar.)

[image]

Comment: Interesting. It can be 2 reasons: A) Bug in MySQL: Check the same database in MariaDB 10.1.7 (beta) for better results, or B) Character set/collation settings of the system: An alphabet with different ordering has been selected (See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collation-effect.html)

Comment: What happens if you say `ORDER BY name, firstname`?  If you say `ORDER BY TRIM(name)` ?

Comment: Can you post the structure of the table and some test data?

Comment: @wchiquito I added an screenshot.

Comment: It shouldn't be possible for K to come before B with `ORDER BY name`. Maybe a blank or even some unprintable character in front? Do you get `Kostic (31)` when you add `AND name like 'K%'`? Do you get `Hatscher (30)` when you add `AND name like 'H%'` instead?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - damn, you are right! There was an unprintable character in front of the K of Kostic. If you write your comment as answer, I'll accept it. (If you wan't the points.)

Comment: Glad, this answered your question. I'll post this as an answer, too, so future readers with the same problem see it immediately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It shouldn't be possible for K to come before H with `ORDER BY name`. Maybe a blank or even some unprintable character in front?

Test:

- Do you get 'Kostic (31)' when you add `AND name like 'K%'`?
- Do you get 'Hatscher (30)' when you add `AND name like 'H%'` instead?

Comment: As already said. It was an unprintable character. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I know ASC is the default when not specified in the ORDER BY but have you tried putting ASC after.. ORDER BY Name ASC. It's worth a shot

Comment: ASC doesn't change anything.